# sort (order) posts by category name (title)

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, posts

I have a parent category and 45-50 sub categories under that. I am trying sort posts by their child category name in archive pages on Wordpress.

By default, wordpress sort them by publishing date; i need them alphabetical (by their category name, NOT "post title")

Let's say A is parent category; i have 45-50 child category under A.
And i need to sort posts which belongs to these categories.
Order by child category name.

Comment: Hi Aşkın Y. Welcome to StackOverflow!  It seems that your question needs some improvements. In order for you to find a faster and more accurate answer to your question it's recommend that you take a look how to ask guide of StackOverflow. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, unfortunately this question does not provide any codes so its not possible for us to help you with this, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this, And also don't forget to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site